# iphone:- MKReverseGeocoder Getting Null Value of postalCode,subAdministrativeArea,locality and subThoroughfare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am Using `MKReverseGeocoder` with `locationManager's` `didUpdateToLocation` delegate But in i am wondering about some value getting null while i am testing app in `Device`.

My code is Bellow:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


     [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // this creates a MKReverseGeocoder to find a placemark using the found coordinates
    reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"MKReverseGeocoder has failed.");
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    NSString *city = myPlacemark.thoroughfare;
    NSString *subThrough=myPlacemark.subThoroughfare;
    NSString *locality=myPlacemark.locality;
    NSString *subLocality=myPlacemark.subLocality;
    NSString *adminisArea=myPlacemark.administrativeArea;
    NSString *subAdminArea=myPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea;
    NSString *postalCode=myPlacemark.postalCode;
    NSString *country=myPlacemark.country;
    NSString *countryCode=myPlacemark.countryCode;


    NSLog(@"city%@",city);
    NSLog(@"subThrough%@",subThrough);
    NSLog(@"locality%@",locality);
    NSLog(@"subLocality%@",subLocality);
    NSLog(@"adminisArea%@",adminisArea);
    NSLog(@"subAdminArea%@",subAdminArea);
    NSLog(@"postalCode%@",postalCode);
    NSLog(@"country%@",country);
    NSLog(@"countryCode%@",countryCode);

}
```

**OUTPUT**

`cityDrive-in Road`

`subThrough(null)`

`locality(null)`

`subLocality(null)`

`adminisAreaGujarat`

`subAdminArea(null)`

`postalCode(null)`

`countryIndia`

`countryCodeIN`

**USING CLGeocoder**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // this creates a MKReverseGeocoder to find a placemark using the found coordinates
//    reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
//    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
//    [reverseGeocoder start];

    CLGeocoder *reverseGeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [reverseGeo reverseGeocodeLocation: newLocation completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"%@",[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
         for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {



             NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~%@",placemark.locality);

         }


     }];
}
```

`OUTPUT IS:- ~~~~~~~~(null)`

My above code Working Properly in simulator but not in Device.. :( Please Help and guide me on proper way to get city name

Comment: Have you ever been able to fix the issue? I seem to get the street, city, country except 'subthoroughfare'... Why is this happening? Does it do anythign with specific country? I am from India. BTW..

Comment: this is not sure every time we get the result MKReverseGeocoder as it has been depreciated by apple in iOS5 so we neet to use its alternative.

Comment: So, what is the alternative solution? BTW. I am using CLGeocoder object to do reverse geocode but it doesn't seem to show up certain info like postalCode, subthoroughFare (door number). Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really use MKReverseGeocoder as it has been depreciated by apple in iOS5, you should really use CLGeocoder. The CLGeocode will return a information which is based in the NSArray *placemarks, you can then iterate through them and call the keys in the assoc array.
Please go through the link.

[CLGeoCode Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Related sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097)

Comment: i am also using CLGeocode but still same prob see my updated question

Comment: I used the your updated code at my end and it works fine for me.Please make sure you are getting updated location (latitude,longitude) in newLocation.

Comment: Brother in my iphone os io6 and i am working in xcode4.5.1 its run well in simulator prob in only device..:(